# ES6 and ES8 syntax in React Component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to ES6 with React, and see this inexplicable code in a component:

```
   componentWillUnmount() {
        base.removeBinding(this.ref);
        this.unsubscribe();
    }

    // ES6 syntax
    handleToggle(event, toggled){
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: toggled,
        });
    };

    // possible ES8 syntax
    handleToggle = (event, toggled) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: toggled,
        });
    };
```

the second method is confusing me, what exactly is happening with the handleToggle method? Is there an ES5 equivalent?

My guess that the ES5 equivalent is:

```
   componentWillUnmount: function() {
        base.removeBinding(this.ref);
        this.unsubscribe();
    }

    handleToggle: (event, toggled) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: toggled,
        });
    };
```

...the problem/confusing part with the second method, is that 'this' in the handleToggle method will be bound to the wrong value (the lexical scope 'this' value)...so is this syntax even valid here?

what is going on? This is code in someone else's library that I wish to understand.

Answer (score 4):

> what exactly is happening with the handleToggle method?

This is a new feature that is a [*proposal*](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) called [*public class fields*](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/). Currently the ES6 class syntax only provides syntactic support for defining shared methods, but not for instance methods/properties. This proposals extend the class syntax to support that.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Foo {
  bar = 42;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 42;
  }
}
```

I.e. those properties are evaluated as if they are assign to `this` inside the constructor.

Consequently your example is equivalent to

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor()
    this.handleToggle = (event, toggled) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: toggled,
        });
    };
  }
}
```

Due to the nature of arrow functions, this creates "bound" instance methods and thus can be passed to other functions without loosing the value of `this`.

> so is this syntax even valid here?

No officially released version of ECMAScript contains this feature, so strictly speaking the answer should be: no. However, it is on the standards track, so it will likely be part of ES2018.

In the meantime its possible to use this proposal in your own code by using Babel (which needs to be used for React anyway) with the [`transform-class-properties` plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edited the title to reflect the new info

Comment: FWIW, in theory ES2018 would be ES9. Better stick to the `ES20YY` notation to avoid confusion. Given that the proposal is at stage 2, I don't expect it to be part of ES2017 (but I could be wrong of course, nobody can predict the future) ;) A term to refer to any future proposal would be something like "ES next" though. See also the [tag:ecmascript-next] tag.

Answer (score 0):

The handleToggle function here makes use of the arrow functions

```
handleToggle = (event, toggled) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: toggled,
    });
};
```

It takes two arguments `event, toggled` and whatever is after the `=>` is the body of the function. One speciality of arrow functions is that is does the binding action too.

The ES5 equivalent of the above function would be

```
handleToggle: function(event, toggled){
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: toggled,
    });
};
```

while calling this function you will need to bind it explicitly like `this.handleToggle.bind(this, value)`

Comment: according to this artcile, the snytax in question is ES8?! https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Comment: np, I think the ES5 equivalent you showed is not correct